# Why is 4.7.7 CiviMail failing trying to insert a row into civicrm_mailing_recipient?

Tags: civimail

To reproduce ...

1. Create a mailing that includes contact X as a recipient
2. Delete the email address of X
3. Send mailing

The job fails trying to send an email to X. Each time the job runs it queues emails to send to the same set of contacts (those 'before' X). Job never completes.

I suspect it's a side-effect of https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-18345

Answer (score 1):

See issue [CRM-18543](https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-18543) and PR [8355](https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/8355).

CRM-18345 changed the behaviour of the foreign keys on civicrm_mailing_recipient when deleting civicrm_email or civicrm_phone. The email_id and phone_id columns are made NULL rather than the row being cascade deleted.

This means there can exist rows in civicrm_mailing_recipient where both these fields are NULL.

So the Mailing Job software needs to handle rows where BOTH email_id and phone_id are NULL.

I've supplied a patch that handles this case by ignoring such rows.